# I'm having trouble with the for(x) in (y) function

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I am currently trying to define a function that looks at two strings and tells the user if one string is located in the other, it looks like this:

```
def isIn(x, y):

    for x in y:
        if x == y:
            print "True"
            print "x in y"
        else:
            print "False"

    for y in x:
        if x == y:
            print "True"
            print "y in x"
        else:
            print "False"

isIn('5', '1')
```

I think it has something to do with the for(x) in (y) function, but I might be wrong. The code keeps coming up with:

```
True
x in y
True 
y in x
```

Any suggestions as to how I might be able to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confusing `for ... in` with just plain `in`;

```
def isIn(x,y):

  if x in y:
    print "True"
    print "x in y"
  else:
    print "False"

  if y in x:
    print "True"
    print "y in x"
  else:
    print "False"

isIn('5','1')
```

Comment: Thanks! My function is functional now.

Answer (score 3):

How about something simpler?

```
def isIn(x, y):
    return x in y or y in x
```

If we're dealing with whole strings and we're interested in knowing if one is part of the other, there's no need to iterate over each of their chars - that will only tell you if some char is in both strings.

Now If you really need to know if some *char* is in both strings, this will do nicely:

```
def isIn(x, y):
    return any(c in y for c in x)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for x in y:
```

`x` here is not an `x` passed to the function. The same for:

```
if x == y:
```

`x` in `for` loop will iterate over `y` and will be `1`. Then you compare it with `y`, which is `1` too. So, you get an expected output:

```
True
x in y
```

The same for the second loop

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues with loops here:

```
for x in y:
    # at this point, x is the first element of '1', so both x and y are '1'
    # thus, x == y, which explains the behavior that you see
```

Ditto for the second loop

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is almost certainly that your code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
def isIn(x, y):

    for x in y:
        pass # abbreviated for brevity. Makes no difference here

    for y in x:
        pass #ditto
```

Your first `for x in y` sequentially assigns to `x` each element in `y`. At the end, `x` is left with the last value in `y`. Then, your next loop reuses the variable name `y`, and binds it sequentially to each element in the last value of `x` from the previous loop.

This doesn't cause an error in your examples because each element of a string is a string of length 1, which is therefore iterable (but only to yield a single object which is value equal to itself).